# npm install --timing not saving full debug log

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm running `npm install --timing`, and when it completes it will output something like:

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mesher/.npm/_logs/2022-05-14T18_33_08_821Z-debug.log
```

Problem is, that debug log does **not** contain a complete log.

Looking at that file, I see that it only has a little over 15k lines, and the first line in the file starts at over line 110k:

```
110055 silly postinstall big.js@5.2.2
110056 info lifecycle big.js@5.2.2~postinstall: big.js@5.2.2
110057 silly postinstall emojis-list@3.0.0
110058 info lifecycle emojis-list@3.0.0~postinstall: emojis-list@3.0.0
...
```

Is there a way to get an **actual** complete npm install log?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you add `--loglevel verbose` to your command all of your logs will be printed to STDERR, as well being saved to `npm-debug.log` in your current directory like `--timing` does. However, this should provide more information around the error:

```
npm install --loglevel verbose
```

This should get you a more complete log file. You can find more about how npm handles [logging in the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/logging).

Answer (score 0):

Even though [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/logging) mentions timing outputting log file path regardless the exit status it does not do that alone. (at least not in 9.7.2)

To actually see the file you have to increase the log level to `info` which would append additional output to the end:

```
# npm i --loglevel info --timing
npm info Timing info written to: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-04T07_33_05_141Z-timing.json
npm info A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-04T07_33_05_141Z-debug-0.log
```

`2023-07-04T07_33_05_141Z-debug-0.log` file will contain complete log with all log levels prefixed at the beginning, here's a sample:

```
18 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 6ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 1ms
21 verbose title npm i
22 verbose argv "i" "--loglevel" "verbose"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 3ms
```

Path log file can also be found by adding `--loglevel verbose` and `--loglevel silly` to the command. These output the most complete results from the log file excluding timing. The path to the log will be logged differently this way, similar to:

```
# npm i --loglevel verbose
npm verb logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-04T07_36_18_275Z-
npm verb logfile C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-04T07_36_18_275Z-debug-0.log
```

You can either read the file to see a complete log or write it to stderr by combining `timing` and `silly` log levels together:

```
npm i --loglevel silly --timing
```

If any command crashes the log file path will be available in the output by default, but there's a better way to handle logs universally.

The location of the file can be changed by defining `--logs-dir`. With this flag NPM will save the whole `.log` file into a defined folder, then you can read the folder if you're looking for an automatic way to locate the file this may as well be a workaround since other solutions are somewhat inconsistent and require parsing the NPM's output.

```
npm i --logs-dir ./
```

I decided to create this answer due to inconsistencies in the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/logging). What is described works differently and I wanted to finally ensure the behavior.